# Lines between columns (column-rule) don't move when window resizes in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm having a problem adding rules between multi-column text in Chrome (I'm using Version 48.0.2564.109 and Mac OS X 10.11.3). When a page first loads, the rules appear as they should between columns, but if the width of the window changes, the rules don't move (but they do if I load the same page in Safari or Firefox).

[Column rules display correctly (top) until viewport is expanded (right) or contracted (left)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5L2mM.jpg)

Is there a way to fix this? (Note: I've exaggerated the width of the rules in the code below to make it easier to see them.)

```css
.text {
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-width: 10em;
  -webkit-column-gap: 30px;
  -webkit-column-rule: 5px solid #000;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-width: 10em;
  -moz-column-gap: 30px;
  -moz-column-rule: 5px solid #000;
  column-count: 3;
  column-width: 10em;
  column-gap: 30px;
  column-rule: 5px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
    elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
    dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit
    anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
    velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
    nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: you can add `word-wrap: break-word;` to the paragraph css

Comment: for some reason, the example at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_column-rule
does(!) work in chrome. Still haven't found out why, though :-(

Comment: I have create a Bugreport in the chromium Issue-tracker: 
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=587794

Comment: Thanks for confirming the bug and creating the report. I had no idea there was a public-facing system that allowed users to do that.

Comment: as of Apr. 15th 2016 the Bug is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its obviously a bug too in chrome for windows.

a work around would be to draw the ruler in the background:

---

[demo with personnalized rulers](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dGLQNR?editors=1100)

---

```css
.text {
  background:linear-gradient(to left,white,black,black,gray) 33% repeat-y,linear-gradient(to right,black,gray,lightgray,gray,black) 67% repeat-y tomato ;/* use any colors even mixed to mimic ridge, groove, double, ... or any creation of yours */
  min-width:35em;/* make sure it does draw 3 cols */
  background-size:5px 5px, 10px 5px;/* sets width of rulers*/
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-width: 10em;
  -webkit-column-gap: 30px;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-width: 10em;
  -moz-column-gap: 30px;
  column-count: 3;
  column-width: 10em;
  column-gap: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
    elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
    dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit
    anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
    velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
    nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: as of Apr. 15th 2016 the Bug is fixed.